# Removing an item from an array during a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following `foreach` being performed in PHP.

What I would like to do is instead of the `$invalid_ids[] = $product_id;` building and then looping around that, I would instead like to remove the entry from array that is being looped around as I'm looping around it..

For example:

If the current `$product_id` fails any of the test, delete the item from the `$current_list` array and proceed to the next iteration of the `foreach` loop.

I tried to do an `unset($product_id)` while the `foreach` loop header looked like this: `foreach ($current_list as &$product_id) {`, but the item item is still in the array.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

```
foreach ($current_list as $product_id) {
    // Test 1 - Is the product still active?
    // How to test? - Search for a product in the (only active) products table 

    $valid = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " WHERE products_id = " . $product_id . " AND products_status = 1");
    // Our line to check if this is okay.

    if ($valid->RecordCount <= 0) { // We didn't find an active item.
        $invalid_ids[] = $product_id;
    }

    // Test 2 - Is the product sold out? 
    if ($valid->fields['products_quantity'] <= 0 and STOCK_ALLOW_CHECKOUT == "false") { // We found a sold out item and it is not okay to checkout.
        $invalid_ids[] = $product_id; 
    }

    // Test 3 - Does the product have an image?
    if (empty($valid->fields['products_image'])) { // Self explanatory.
        $invalid_ids[] = $product_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simple code may help you

let's say we have an array of integers and we want to remove all the items that are equal to "2" inside of the foreach loop

```
$array = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{
   if($value==2)
      unset($array[$key]);
}
var_dump($array);
```

this shows the following result

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1
  2 => int 1
  4 => int 1
  6 => int 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`$product_id` isn't the actual data in the array, it's a copy of it. You would need to `unset` the item from `$current_list`.

I'm don't know how `$current_list` is stored, but something like `unset($current_list['current_item']` would do the trick. You can use `key` to select the `current_item` key in the array.

A similar way of iterating the Array, where you can get the array key, from the PHP [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) docs...

```
while ($fruit_name = current($array)) {
    if ($fruit_name == 'apple') {
        echo key($array).'<br />';
    }
    next($array);
}
```

Untested, but something like this...

```
while ($product_id = current($current_list)) {

    // Do your checks on $product_id, and if it needs deleting...
    $keyToDelete = key($array);
    unset($current_list[$keyToDelete]);

    next($current_list);
}
```

Comment: `$current_list` is also an array that was built early in the function. But I shall try your answer anyway.